# Define a constant with placeholder

Tags: javascript

I have an api call with a link, which contains a variable. Instead of coding the link every time I want to hide that in a constant. E.g.

```
var apiRoutes = {
    'test + {placeholder}': "pre/" + {placeholder} + "/post",
}
```

I want to call the api via

```
apiRoutes.test{variable}.
```

Is that possible with JavaScript? Probably with regular expressions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Some more information. Is there any solution?

```
var apiRoutes = {
    'register': baseurl + '/api/user/register', //fix route
    'login': baseurl + '/api/user/login', //fix route
    [...]
    'test {placeholder}': "pre/" + { placeholder } + "/post", //what I want to do. This code won't solve my problem
}
[...]
window.location.href = apiRoutes .register;
window.location.href = apiRoutes .login;
window.location.href = apiRoutes .test{example_id_1}; //what I want to do. This code won't solve my problem
```

Comment: What `+` doing in `test + {placeholder}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a dynamic property to `apiRoutes` using the bracket notation, e.g. `apiRoutes['test' + placeholder] = ...`. You can also access/read it using the same notation:

```js
var placeholder = 'foobar';
var apiRoutes = { };
apiRoutes['test' + placeholder] = 'pre/' + placeholder + '/post';

console.log(apiRoutes);
console.log(apiRoutes['test' + placeholder]);
```

If you can use ES6, you can also use template strings/literals:

```js
const placeholder = 'foobar';
const apiRoutes = { };
apiRoutes[`test${placeholder}`] = `pre/${placeholder}/post`;

console.log(apiRoutes);
console.log(apiRoutes[`test${placeholder}`]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure if I understand it or use it right. With your solution I implement a fix route in the array, but I want to make the call variable like

console.log(apiRoutes['test' + foo1]);
console.log(apiRoutes['test' + foo2]);
console.log(apiRoutes['test' + foon]);

Comment: @AndreasInfo If `foo1`, `foo2` and etc. refer to a string I don't see why that's a problem.